# How to get the current operating system architecture in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I am trying to write code that needs the current operating system architecture, specifically it needs the same architecture that binaries are compiled with. On my system it is `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`.

Answer (score 4):

Found it: [`:erlang.system_info(:system_architecture)`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#system_info_system_architecture).